# XMLPullParser Android test for attribute

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML file with some strings:

```
<string>foo</string>
```

and some strings contain an href attribute:

```
<string href="http://www.google.com/">foo2</string>
```

I am using XMLPullParser to parse this XML in my Android app. However, I need to be able to test whether the xml element contains the href attribute. Or any attribute at all for that matter.
I tried using this:

```
private boolean testForHref(String tag) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
    try{
        parser.getAttributeValue(NULL, tag);
        System.out.println("href attribute is here!");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("href attribute is not here!");
        return false;
    }

}
```

But this does always return false. Does anyone know how to do this test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
```

For more info check `readLink` method in the parser example below

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Example:

XMl

```
<mojiva> // root tag
<string href="10.80.30.10/tracker">Issue tracker</string> // string tag with attribute
</mojiva>
```

Parsing

```
  parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "mojiva");
   while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
       if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
           continue;
       }
       String name = parser.getName();
       if (name.equals("string")) {
           String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
           Log.i("....................","Hello......"+relType);

       } else {
           skip(parser);
       }
   }
```

Log

```
12-18 03:26:41.052: I/....................(1417): Hello......10.80.30.10/tracker
```

Comment: This keeps returning null on this: <string href="http://10.80.30.10/tracker">Issue tracker</string>

Comment: @BlackMagic it will work. i don't know how you do our parsing.

Comment: I figured it out, I read the tag and then skipped to the next tag, and tried reading the attribute on that one, but obviously that won't work xD But thanks for your help!

Comment: @BlackMagic what won't work. i don't understand. what i posted is working. So what is that you want exactly??

Comment: In my own code, I had a method for reading the tag. This method read the tag and skipped to the next tag. I called this before trying to read the attribute. So it was trying to read the attribute of the next tag instead of the one I wanted it to read

Comment: This will work for a single element, but for multiple elements, you have to run the while loop as `XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT`. You should mention that

Comment: @BibaswannBandyopadhyay you need to look at the docs already posted. this is relevant to the question posted